# How do I set up Private Name severs at names.example - Glue Record Errors

Tags: domains, dns, nameserver

Missing Glue Record

there. I am trying to point my domain registered at `names.example` to my private name servers. However the process fails with a message from `names.example` telling me:

> Required parameter missing. V024 Missing Glue record for server `ns1.mydomain.example`.

Pretty sure I have the correct settings in `names.example` control panel (as below) with both ns1 & ns2 subdomains registered to the new IPs via A record:

DNS Settings:

- Add/Modify DNS Zone: `mydomain.example`

  - A, CNAME, AAAA, TXT and NS records

    - 'Host Name' 'Type' 'Result'

      - **ns1         A      xx.xx.xx.11**
      - **ns2         A      xx.xx.xx.22**

Then added the name server addresses:

Change Nameservers:

- Change Nameservers: `mydomain.example`

  - Primary nameserver*

    - `ns1.mydomain.example`
  - Secondary nameserver*

    - `ns2.mydomain.example`

Domain/Service(s): `www.mydomain.example`

My dig produces:

```
dig mydomain.example any @xx.xx.xx.11

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> mydomain.example any @xx.xx.xx.11
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 22440
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomain.example.      IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.example.   14400   IN  TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:xx.xx.xx.52 ~all"
mydomain.example.   14400   IN  MX  0 mydomain.example.
mydomain.example.   86400   IN  SOA ns1.mydomain.example. info.mydomain.example. 2015061103 86400 7200 3600000 86400
mydomain.example.   86400   IN  NS  ns1.mydomain.example.
mydomain.example.   86400   IN  NS  ns2.mydomain.example.
mydomain.example.   14400   IN  A   xx.xx.xx.11

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mydomain.example.   14400   IN  A   xx.xx.xx.11
ns1.mydomain.example.   14400   IN  A   xx.xx.xx.11
ns2.mydomain.example.   14400   IN  A   xx.xx.xx.22

;; Query time: 93 msec
;; SERVER: xx.xx.xx.11#53(xx.xx.xx.11)
;; WHEN: Sat Jun 13 10:38:40 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 241
```

Comment: Have you tried pinging or tracerouting to your nameserver subdomains?

Comment: Thank you. No, I assumed I couldn't do that as due to the V024 error the link between name and IP has not been created yet and as such the old DNS settings are still pointing to the old nameserver

Comment: Having been a webhost in a previous life, I highly recommend NOT running your own DNS servers unless your business model requires that you are a SOA for *other domains*. You do not want your own DNS records on your DNS servers without at least external backup. It leaves absolutely no room for error and it almost impossible to do otherwise. It is always always always wise to host your DNS records outside of your domain and not on your NS at least for for your SOA and primary records.

Comment: 100% agree with closetnoc.    Don't run your own DNS servers unless you have to.   Reliable DNS hosting is very cheap or even free.   Many DNS registrars offer it as a free service with domain registration.   Many hosting companies offer it as a free service with web hosting.   You can pay pennies for it at hosts like Amazon Route 53.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Patrick [says](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/106013/), you need your registrar to put a glue record in place with your nameserver subdomains and IP addresses.  I've been running a split horizon network like this for many years with my own master and backup nameservers only exposed though IPv6 and external backup DNS servers providing IPv4/6, with transfers from the master nameserver.  I had to ask my registrar to use only the IPv6 addresses specifically because the web interface doesn't allow for it.

This allowed the the use of a dynamic external IPv4 address and a routed IPv6 /48 subnet from an IPv6 tunnel broker.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your name servers are in-bailiwick of your domain name: since you want `example.co.uk` to use `ns1.example.co.uk` and `ns2.example.co.uk` as name servers, to prevent a DNS resolution loop, you need to have them as glue records on registry name servers which means you need to register first these name servers at the registry with their IP addresses, and only after that you will be able to use them for your domain name.

You need to do that through your registrar, you either ask him to do it for you or they provide some kind of interface for you to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I used dns settings and just filled it in with my name servers the type A and with ip address to server

Second is NS TYPE with name as ns1 and value is  ns1.domain.com

Comment: And on my testing domain just add in the name servers under name servers